# Identify visible portion of an element which has an overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to be able to find out what text of an element (could be a div or textbox) are currently visible when there is an overflow.

As the user scrolls up and down I need to have an updated list of visible text.

I have no restrictions as to what elements to use except that only a portion of the text will be visible so naturally I think of a div or a textbox.

HTML Part:

```
<div id="box">
    <p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p>
    <p>4</p><p>5</p><p>6</p>
    <p>7</p><p>8</p><p>9</p>
    <p>10</p><p>11</p><p>12</p>
</div>
<div id="result">
    Visible Items: 
</div>
```

CSS Part:

```
#box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: yellow;
}
#result{
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#box" ).scroll(function() {
  $("#result").append("Hello");
});
```

In the example, in the green div I originally want to see: '1' '2' and '3' but as the user scrolls down it will change to '2' '3' '4' and so on.

[See a js fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/vtVz9/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function should tell you whether an element is entirely visible:

```
var isVisible = function(elem, container) {
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).outerHeight();
    return elemTop >= 0 && elemBottom <= $(container).outerHeight();
}
```

If you need to know whether something is partially visible this should work:

```
var isVisible = function(elem, container) {
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).outerHeight();
    return elemBottom > 0 && elemTop < $(container).outerHeight();
}
```

These are assuming we are only worried about vertical scrolling.

The jsfiddle fork is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9F5eh/

Comment: Interesting and simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this plugin](http://opensource.teamdf.com/visible/examples/demo-basic.html).

or you must  calculate any element offsets.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$( "#box" ).scroll(function() {
    var left = $('#box').offset().left;
    var top = $('#box').offset().top;
    var right = left + $('#box').width();
    var bottom = top + $('#box').height();
    var elems = $('#box').children('p').filter( function(i) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        return (offset.left >= left && offset.left <= right) && (offset.top >= top && offset.top <= bottom);
    } );

    //elems contains all elements we consider 'in view'
    $('#result').html('');
    elems.each( function( e ) {
        $('#result').append( $(this).html() + ', ' );
    } );
});
```

You calculate the values for each of the edges of the box. Then you get all the elements inside this box, and see if the top left of this element is in view. If this is true, we make the filter keep that element, otherwise we discard the item. Therefore we end up with all elements 'in view' in `elems`.

Documentation: [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4pAge/

Comment: I'm only interested in vertical scrolling but I'll keep this in mind for horizontal too.